Is there any trick portrait photographers use to make nostrils not stick out too much? Or is it a sensor size, focal length issue?
I've seen this on few top supermodels. In some of their photographs, their nostrils appear to stick out and in some other photos, their nostrils seem tucked in. The models make the same expression in all of the photos. I can't say anything about what sensor size and focal length they use for these photos but the distance between the photographer and the models appears to be similar in all of the photos.
I don't know if this is due to make up. But I want to know if there are any photography tricks involved to achieve this, like fix a focus spot on the nose tip and take few steps back or use a special focal length with a sensor size.
For the sake of this topic, disregard the possibility of air brushing or digital editing.
Some examples:

Notice in the 1st photo, her nostrils stick out, in the 2nd photo they don't stick out that much. I'm unable to find the exact photos in which she was doing the same expression. But there are such photos too.

Would be very helpful if you got some examples.

@EuriPinhollow How do I do it? Can I post in the original post or add links or add them in the comments.

@bypassrestrictions please add them to your original post. If you cannot directly post images, use an image host and add the links instead.

@bypassrestrictions unless there's any copyright prohibiting posting the image here it's best to embed them in the question.

@EuriPinhollow I've added photos.

same model but the lighting is different, the second has more fill from the left. Lighting will 'sculpt/model' a models face, the second looks more high key. The first, the left nostril falls into darkness, the second has it brought back into light. Quite different post on the first, but the quality of light is different, sculpting the features differently

@blobbymcblobby Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short

@scottbb - I wasn't sure i actually had an answer though, so I was just holding off really...

What do you mean by "stick out"? I don't really see any great difference in the nostrils of the model in the photos. That is, I see nothing particularly unnatural. The crop is different of course, which can influence what you might notice or feel is prominent.

maybe she just flared her nostrils when the shot was taken, lol

"For the sake of this topic, disregard the possibility of air brushing or digital editing." Ha, ha, ha... good one! These are ALL heavily edited.

@MichaelC Color grading is different digital editing, like making a feature prominent or removing wrinkles and blemishes.

@blobbymcblobby I know at least two people who are like carbon copies of her but both of their nostrils look like the 1st pic, so I'm confused why hers look like that in some photos and why her nostrils look tucked in different photos.

Can she pr they suck in their nostrils as a talent? You never know, I've shot some very good chameleons...

@blobbymcblobby In her latest photoshoot, they stick out, she is a very confusing model. The two people I know grew up eating spicy food, so the food probably permanently expanded their nostrils. Karolina Kurkova probably ate less spicy food, so her nostrils were not permanently damaged.

wow, I've never heard that connection..! I don't eat much spicey food but I'm sure I can still get a corn dog up there, not sure the two are linked. (I guess your friends didn't stick enough butter (or olive oil) up their holes to help at the time)

@blobbymcblobby Your comment is confusing, spicy foods makes the nose runny, to allow the mucous to flow, the nostrils expand, eating spicy food regularly could make the nostrils permanently expand.

@bypassrestrictions And these have plenty of both color grading and spot editing. Probably frequency separation, whether manual or automated, as well.

How visible the nostrils are, depends on these factors:
Head posture
Obviously, if the model tilts the head back ever so slightly, more nostril will be visible. If the head is slightly tilted down, you see less.
However, there are some effects even if you shoot the photo dead-on:
View plane of the Camera
Especially in your example image, you can see that while in both cases the camera points directly to the face, the height of the camera is different.
In image one, the camera in on the height of the tip of the nose, maybe even the upper lip. This perspective allows to view more of the nose from below.
Image two has the camera on eye level. This means we are now more looking down on the nose from above, so that we are seeing less nostrils.
Focus Length
And second the focal length of the lens used. The focal length translates to the angle of view, which changes the look of an image drastically.
A short focal length or wide-angle lens over-pronounces the size of closer objects or features to the lens. This can make a nose to look more prominent, as it is closer to the lens. The effect is getting even more prominent, the closer the subject is to the lens (with a wide angle lens, you need to be much closer to the subject for filling the frame with it).
You will notice:

Noses pointing towards the camera will look like sticking out
Oval head shapes will tend to look more oval
Ears seem to appear to be flatter on the head
The changes of the camera level will be more apparent due to the wider view angle. If you are lower, then the wider angle will make the nostrils even more visible. If you are higher, even less nostrils will be visible.

A longer focal or telephoto lens on the other hand under-pronounces sticking out feature, so that faces tend to look flatter.
Effect:

Faces will look flatter with noses not sticking out
Heads will look a bit rounder
Ears will appear more like the are. There is no artificial "wrapping around" effect.


Note that the focal length shown here are on a full frame camera.
So why would anyone use a wide angle lens in portraiture?
There can be several reasons.

A wide angle lens can help cover some feature, like sticking out ears.
It allows you to get very close to the model, and this can create a feeling on intimacy.
It allows you to capture more of the surrounding of the model, which is useful if that context is needed for the photo's message.
At a lot of people are used to the look due to their mobile phone cameras also being on the wide-angle side, so they might find their image looking more familiar.
It can create a photo that looks more dynamic by using the skewing effect to emphasize e.g. movement.

Summed up

The top image seems to use a longer focal length and is shot on a lower view plane, which makes the face rounder, the nose sticking out less but also gives a view of the nostrils
The second image is shot a bit wider, making the head more oval, the nose a bit more prominent, but also due to the higher view plane helps to hide the nostrils.


I've added photos in the my OP.

@bypassrestrictions I have added the primary effect here: the viewing plane to my answer

It's NOT the focal length that affects perspective. It's the different shooting distances used to get the same framing with different focal lengths. To mention focal length and totally ignore that the example images were all shot at different distances is irresponsible and leads to perpetuating the myth that focal length determines perspective when the ONLY thing that affects perspective is subject distance. Period.

Actually, the focal length determines what the angle of view is and the the angle of view determines the distance to the subject if you want to have the same projection size of the subject. So yes, the main factor is the distance, but for all practical means it is the combination of viewing angle and distance play its role.

@KaiMattern Focal length combined with sensor/film size determine angle of view. You'll get a very different angle of view using an 325mm lens on, say an 8x10 view camera than you will with, say, a Micro Four-Thirds camera. The former is a 43mm equivalent AoV, the latter is a 650mm equivalent AoV. [Equivalent being the focal length lens needed to give that AoV on a 135 format camera with a 24x36mm sensor or film plane.]

Yes, indeed. But I state in my answer that I assume an equivalent of 35mm film sensor size. Also that dismisses your comment that only the distance is the main factor. There are a lot of factors going in. If that depth will help the OP, I have no idea. ;o)


Is there any trick portrait photographers use to make nostrils not stick out too much? Or is it a sensor size, focal length issue?


I originally had just a comment as I didnt think it was enough for an answer, but:
Based on the photos that you added (and before that it was really hard to read the question), it sort of feels like you've asked the wrong question.
I mean yes, despite what is often said, gear does matter, and as others have already said, lens length, distance, etc all matter.
But, so does lighting. And make up, but in this case, the lighting is important. And posing! (And height of camera with regards to models face)
So:
It looks the same model, but the lighting is different, the second has more fill from the left. Pose is slightly different.
Check the catch lights.
Lighting will 'sculpt/model' a models face, and the second photo looks more high key.
The first, the left nostril falls into darkness, the second has it brought back into light.
Quite different post (eg. desat) on the first as well (you said to ignore that though), but the quality of light is different, sculpting the features differently
Also, although the model has differing expression, the pose is slightly different too, the top is more of a chin forward near pout, the bottom reminds me of a standard beauty shot.
Anyway, all these things result in different looks.
(The model is Karolina Kurkova, first image is 2001, the latter around a decade later, so some changes also possible in skin,tightening,sagging,fattening, etc over years)
Note, Kurkova has a pretty distinctive nose structure though, tip a degree here, there, or the other way and it does lend itself to giving a different look, I think you picked a difficult example there...

(note collage above - nose down, hide nostrils; nose up, peekaboo!)

Notice in the 1st photo, her nostrils stick out, in the 2nd photo they don't stick out that much.

Second photo - does not 'stick out' so much because: lighting is different, the pose is different (nose more down in 2nd, chin more forward, making nose up in 1st) - the model has a long nose with protruding tip, so the tip kind of hides the nostrils when in a more down position, when up the the nostrils are more exposed - with different models this varies)

With nostrils, do you mean the nose holes or the round structures on the sides of nose tip. In the collage you posted, in some photos, even when the nose is pointing downwards, you can nostrils stick out on the sides. But in some photos it is not visible. In 2nd photo I posted, the camera appears to be slightly lower, the lighting is higher, nose is not more down as you say, still nostrils don't stick out that much on sides.

i meant more the holes in general, rather than the alar fibrofatty sidewalls, but didnt mean it to be black and white either - just pointing out reasons potentially why you see more or less of the same model in the two different photos. Theres variation between the two in terms of height of the camera with regards to the face, the angle up or down of the face and therefore nose, whether its the model or the camera or both, and the lighting, and the post. The collage isnt a hard example, just what i found on a single page.

After you've added the examples your question seems much narrower than I originally thought.
First of all, speaking of nose appearance overall it looks to me that nose stands out more on the 2nd photo.
Speaking of nostrils, I see the difference which you are talking about. In general, nostrils are two cavities separated by extending skin piece.

the form of separating hanging skin can differ, the form of nostrils (the edge) can differ, their size can differ. Nose is not a standard face feature obviously.
angle of view (upwards vs downwards relatively to the face) directly affects how large the nostrils appear on the photo because of pure geometry. If model looks downwards you won't see nostrils at all
nostrils have some muscles and their appearance differs when inhaling deeply for example. There are muscles under the nose too.
in this case there seems to be no difference in lighting but in general darker shadows in the nostrils will put more accent on them

These factors seem most important to me.

Re: your first point. It's the same model, and most likely the same nose (i.e. no plastic surgery between #1 and #2).

You need to find the diagonal measure of your camera's format. As an example, a full frame 35mm measures 24mm height by 36mm length. The diagonal measure of this rectangle is 44mm. A good choice focal length for this format is a lens 2.5X the diagonal measurement. This works out to 44 x 2.5 = 110mm. Using a 100mm thru 120mm will force you step back as you compose a portrait. It's the stepping back that solves nose too big and ears too small perspective error.
If you have an APS-C camera, the format dimensions are 16mm height by 24mm length and the diagonal measure is 30mm. For this lash-up it is suggested that a lens focal length 30 X 2.5 = 75mm (approximately) will do this deed.
Again find out the diagonal measure of your camera's format. A good choice for portrait lens focal length is 2 1/2 times this value.

Thanks for this valuable insight. Can check my OP with images? Is the same thing at work?

Find out the make and model of the camera and then go to the web and find the specifications of the camera to gain the dimensions of its imagining chip.

Working the camera in too close induces exaggerated perspective. We are taking oversize nose and limbs. If you use a moderate telephoto, you will certainly step back as you compose. Technically, this act moves the perspective frame of the set-up forward. This simple act suppresses an exaggerated perspective. In other words, a 2X thru 2 ½ X telephoto is what the pros use when doing head and shoulder portraits.

Were you a portrait photographer?

For many years I was an instructor at the Professional Photographers of America School summer school for continuing education (Wynona). My subject was Color Print and Process. The genuine portrait pros taught summer courses on portraiture. I often attended and helped out as a grip. Years of monitoring forced some of the curriculum (portraiture) to stick. In those days the PPA was a powerful guild.
